# Remove Column from the data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting error while trying to remove the column "Unnamed:0" from the data frame.

Attached the Error File.[Error file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxkIV.png)

Comment: There is space, `"Unnamed: 0"` between colon and 0.

Comment: Hiya, I tried the options but still donot pick the code. Do you get the result?

Comment: `Advertising.drop(Advertising.columns.values[0], axis =1, inplace = True)`

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a mismatch of the actual label string with your input. Try `Advertising.columns` to get a list of the actual label strings to inspect. You can always copy/paste or get the first element from there to be sure you have it right.